# POSTing JSON w/ node.js

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, post

I have two node.js files: "client" and "server".  "Server" just listens for any http requests, and then writes the request object to console when it is received.  This works as expected for GET requests.  When I write a client like the one below that POSTs JSON, it *seems* to work fine except there is no JSON anywhere in the request that is output to console on "Server".

In the output that "server" prints to console, all the other request specific things are there, such as host: '127.0.0.1', url: '/some/path', method: 'POST'

But no reference to any of the JSON that was POSTed....items like username:'someUser',email:'some@email.com',firstName: 'SomeFN',lastName: 'SomeLN'

complete console output from "Server" is [here](http://pastebin.com/2EgYbR1s).

```
//client
var http = require('http');

var user = {
  username: 'someUser',
  email: 'some@email.com',
  firstName: 'SomeFN',
  lastName: 'SomeLN'
};

var userString = JSON.stringify(user);

var headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'Content-Length': userString.length
};

var options = {
  host: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 80,
  path: '/some/path',
  method: 'POST',
  headers: headers
};

// Setup the request.  The options parameter is
// the object we defined above.
var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
  res.setEncoding('utf-8');

  var responseString = '';

  res.on('data', function(data) {
    responseString += data;
  });

  res.on('end', function() {
    var resultObject = JSON.parse(responseString);
  });
});

req.on('error', function(e) {
  // TODO: handle error.
});

req.write(userString);
req.end();
```

.

```
//server
var http = require('http'); 
var stringify = require('json-stringify-safe'); 

http.createServer(function (req, res) { 
res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'}); 
res.end(stringify(req, null, 2)); 
console.log(req)
}).listen(80, '127.0.0.1');
```

Comment: Your server needs to listen to 'data' events on the request to get the POST data.

Comment: An `http.Server` doesn't handle any of the body content of a request. It's up to you [read](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_readable) and parse it, same as you have the client doing.

Comment: If you check out the pastebin link, that's (I think) what you're referring to as a readable stream, which you are correct I could parse easily.  The problem is...none of my posted JSON stuff is in that stream.  Or do I need to tweak "server" in some way to capture the JSON?  This is my first node project so....